# Save tf.summary.image with Estimator API

Tags: python, tensorflow

at the moment I trying to get a little bit more familiar with the TF Estimator API. I'm working/learning with the example from this [blog entry](https://medium.com/onfido-tech/higher-level-apis-in-tensorflow-67bfb602e6c0).

Now I have the problem that I'm not able to save a simple image summary (tf.summary.image).

I added a *SummarySaverHook* in the *experiment_fn* and add the hook to the *eval_hooks* parameter of the Experiment constructor:

```
def experiment_fn(run_config, params):
   ...
   summary_hook = tf.train.SummarySaverHook(
      100,
      output_dir='/summeries',
      summary_op=tf.summary.merge_all()
   )
   ...
   experiment = tf.contrib.learn.Experiment(
      estimator=estimator,  # Estimator
      train_input_fn=train_input_fn,  # First-class function
      eval_input_fn=eval_input_fn,  # First-class function
      train_steps=params.train_steps,  # Minibatch steps
      min_eval_frequency=params.min_eval_frequency,  # Eval frequency
      train_monitors=[train_input_hook],  # Hooks for training
      eval_hooks=[eval_input_hook, summary_hook],  # Hooks for evaluation
      eval_steps=None  # Use evaluation feeder until its empty
   )
```

What is not clear to me is where I have to add the *tf.summary.image()* function so that the image will be shown in the image tab of tensorboard.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to add a hook. Just add the `tf.summary.image` call anywhere in your `model_fn`/`input_fn` and the estimator should automatically add a summary hook for all summaries created.

Comment: Thank you very much. When I add the `tf.summary.image` directly in my model_fn everything is working for training mode. But when I try to save the image summary only for evaluation mode the summaries are not saved/shown in Tensorboard `f mode == ModeKeys.EVAL`

Comment: @SebastianMetzler Yeah, I believe getting summary images in eval mode is (unfortunately) an open issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15332

Comment: @random_forest_fanatic Hey, do you know if there are any news for the problem? Is it now possible to save image summaries during the eval phase of an estimator?

Comment: @SebastianMetzler The issue's still open, so I don't think there's been any progress.